# Problema actualizando estado Vuex

Tags: javascript, vuex

Hola tengo el siguiente inconveniente, estoy actualizando el estado desde un componente y mostrando el contenido de esta variable en otro, en el componente que se ejecuta el commit el estado cambia pero en el componente que muestra la informacion no se actualiza.

```
  state: {
    message: 'Message test'
  }      
  newMessage (state) {
    state.message = new Date()
  }      
  changeMessage ({commit}) {
    commit('newMessage')
  }
// Este es el componente que debe mostrar cuando cambio el estado
  div {{message}}
  import { mapState } from 'vuex'
  export default {
    computed: {
      ...mapState({
        message: state => state.message
      }),
    }
  }
```

[image]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes colocar el código donde estas imprimiendo la variable `message`.

Comment: Listo ya lo coloque

Comment: Trate de replicarlo http://jsbin.com/josimologa/edit?html,js,output, aun así me funciona el cambio de estado. Sabes si hay otra información que puedas dar para brindarte ayuda.

Comment: Lo que sucede es que lo haces en un componente, yo el commit a la mutation lo hago desde el componente A en una ventana y quien muestra la info es el componente B eso es lo que me falla que el componente B no muestra el estado actualizado

Answer (score 0):

Para editar los datos en VUEX
hay que hacerlo únicamente a través de las mutaciones
y estas son llamadas en las acciones despachadas

dispatch -> mutation -> state

Es una arquitectura unidireccional, para evitar conflictos y organizar el estado de la aplicación.

```
state: {
    message: 'Message test'
},    
mutations: {
    newMessage (state) {
        state.message = new Date()
    }
},
actions: {
    addMessage ({commit}) {
        commit('newMessage')
    }
}
```

En el componente que cambia el mensaje sería así:

```
methods: {
    addMessage () {
         this.$store.dispatch('addMessage')
    }
}
```

El componente que lee el mensaje, y se actualiza cada vez que cambie:

```
computed: {
    message () {
        return this.$store.state.message
    }
}
```